# how to add any image while digitalsign pdf with secureblackbox

Tags: delphi, digital-signature

I want to Digitalysign PDF documents with SecureBlackBox.
I want to add visible signature and add some jpg as background data.

how do I add this JPG image to the **FSigner.Signature.Background...** property?
what is **CustomBackgroundContentStream** and how can I use it!
I want to have control on the place and size of the image.
SecureBlackBox doesn't include an image in the signer example and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to the internet - it works through links. According to [the documentation](https://cdn.nsoftware.com/help/SBF/dlp/PDFSignerType_PDFSignature.htm#PDFSignature_f_BackgroundData) just load the (JPG) [file via `TFileStream` into `TBytes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67312679/4299358). Really, reading the docs helps. And so does using links when being online.

Comment: Hi Amigojack-, thanks. I never got along with the Byte or with the pointers. And the concept of RTFM is familiar to me but I deserve what you said :).